# How to drop only the number in the same column which has string in object type, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

d = {'col1': ['Son', 2, 'Dad'], 'col2': [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

I want to drop change the second row to 'Unknown'

```
  col1  col2
0  Son     3
1    2     4
2  Dad     5
```

change to

```
     col1  col2
0     Son     3
1 Unknown     4
2     Dad     5
```

Comment: Change number 2 in second row (0, col1) to 'Unknown'

Comment: What should be the output if COL1 was `['Son', 2, 'Dad', '3', float('nan')]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas str functions make numeric to NaN

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str[:].fillna('Unknown')
```

output:

`df`

```
    col1    col2
0   Son     3
1   Unknown 4
2   Dad     5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str)
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('\d+', 'Unknown') #find numbers and replace with "unknown"
```